# Are any English translations of the Parashar Samhita available online?

Tags: scripture, hanuman, translation-request, resource, parashara

The Parashar Samhita is an interesting book that chronicles the life of Lord Hanuman as narrated by **Rishi Parashar**, the author of Parashar Smriti and the Parashar Hora Shastra. I found the Sanskrit version of the text but am not able to find a verse by verse **English translation**. Does anyone know of a credible source?

> [image]

Comment: You mean Parashara smriti?

Comment: Nope.. I know Parashar Smriti is also referred to as the Parashar Dharma Samhita at some places but it is different from the Parashar Samhita

Comment: Thanks @Pandya but this is the same as the Parashar Dharma Samhita. I am uploading an image of the Sanskrit text I have see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I see, not found English translation.

Answer (score 2):

During a Google search, I found online translation of Parasar Sanhita(aplenty chapters about Hanuman). It is available in English and Telugu.

http://www.jayahanumanji.com/?p=2091